# If attribute value equals to... show something

Tags: php, wordpress, attributes

I'm working on something on wordpress + woocommerce.
I've inputed some 'filter' attributes value for some products.

So if the value of the attribute for this product includes a "Wood Grains" value, i want to echo an Woodgrains.jpg on the front end.

Therefore if the value = Texture, i want to echo Texture.jpg icon.

the code below is what i've mustered so far, but this only echoes out all the values tagged to a product, i can't figure out what to change to get the 'if' statement in it.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_filter');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
echo $term->name;
}
```

here's a screenshot of what the code above does on the front end:
http://edleuro.com/new/wp-content/themes/mystile/img/1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a better way to resolve my problem. i had this in my content-product.php woocommerce template.

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_filter');
     foreach($terms as $term){
     if($term->name == 'Wood Grains'){
         echo '<img src="icon_woodgrains.gif">';
     }
    }
?>
```

do take note that the term name is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

If this returns an array of terms for the said product:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_filter');
```

You can check if the returned result array has what you are looking for by doing this:

```
if (in_array("Wood Grains", $terms))
{
    // has it
}
else
{
    // doesn't have it
}
```

---

**Update**

Based in your reply to my answer, I have came up with the following:

*Create a helper function like this:*

```
function termExists($myTerm, $terms)
{
    if (is_array($terms)) {
        foreach ($terms as $id => $data) {
            if ($data->name == $myTerm)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
if (termExists('Wood Grains', get_the_terms($product->id, 'pa_filter')))
{
    // term exists
}
else
{
    // does not exists
}
```

Comment: sorry, so.. i tried but i'm not sure what's wrong. the one liner you wrote, is to replace the whole code i initially wrote above? am i correct?


something like this? 

`if (in_array("Wood Grains", get_the_terms($product->id, 'pa_filter')))
{
 echo "Have a good day!";
}`

Comment: I've updated my post about the one liner. Yes; that's how you use it. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: yes i've tried with the updated one-liner. but it doesnt echo anything unfortunately. i'll try mess around with the code to see if anything comes out. thanks

Comment: Okay, ignore the one-liner. do this `$terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_filter');` and then check like I showed. If it still doesn't work, can you `var_dump($terms);` - i'd like to see it's contents.

Comment: didnt quite understand by your "do this..."

anyway did a var dump. here's the output

`array(1) { [20]=> object(stdClass)#277 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(20) ["name"]=> string(11) "Wood Grains" ["slug"]=> string(11) "wood-grains" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(21) ["taxonomy"]=> string(9) "pa_filter" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) ["object_id"]=> int(13) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } } `

Comment: It looks like you are not getting back a simple array list, instead you are getting back an object array. Can you do this instead: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($terms); echo "</pre>";` and copy the output and paste it to [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) and reply here with the link. I know how to solve this; it's a little hard to see the structure of the data with var_dump, so use print_r like shown.

Comment: okay never mind, I understand the structure now. I have updated my answer. See above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51247/discussion-between-mfk-and-latheesan-kanes)

Answer (score 0):

foreach prints Warning: invalid argument supplied for foreach()…

This works for me "on a purely":

```
if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Wood Grains', 'pa_filter' )) {
    echo '<img src="Texture.jpg">';
}
```